# Logical XOR on SHP Layer using QGIS?

Tags: shapefile, qgis

I'd like to create a difference layer from two shapefiles using QGIS.  I would have thought this is simple - maybe I'm doing something silly.

In the image below there are two layers - the orange one being of higher resolution than the green:

[image: Image of New York]

I'd like isolate the visible green area. I would have thought this is a `Vector -> Geo Processing -> Difference` operation but this doesn't seem to work.

So my question is - how do I create a layer of the visible green area?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you just need to switch around the "Input" and "Difference" layer in the Difference tool.

Example with screenshots:

Select your polygon layer as the input and the countries layer as the difference layer

[image: Qgis Difference tool]

Result is everything from the polygon except countries:

[image: Resulting polygon from difference tool]